# How to run Ubuntu touch apps on Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I see there are some [nice apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/10/winners-of-the-2013-ubuntu-app-showdown/) being developed for Ubuntu touch and that [some of them support larger screens](http://www.jonobacon.org/2013/10/05/karma-machine-an-example-of-ubuntu-app-convergence/). Now, I would like to run some of these apps on my desktop? Is this possible at the moment? If so, how could it be done?

I see that one can [install the core apps](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-play-with-ubuntu-touch-apps-in-ubuntu-12-10), but I haven't found any instruction on installing [click packages](https://click-package.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all done with the help of a PPA. All you have to do is to open a terminal and run the following command (you will need to be root):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touch-coreapps
```

When the installation finishes, you can find the application in Unity Dash. According to Alan Pope, the apps have been tested on Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Source: http://linux.softpedia.com/blog/How-to-Test-and-Use-Ubuntu-Touch-Core-Apps-on-the-Ubuntu-Desktop-433742.shtml

Answer (score 2):

There is experimental emulator for ubuntu 14.04, when someone have it it can be installed from repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-emulator
cp -r /usr/share/android/emulator/ ~/
cd ~/emulator/
./build-emulator-sdcard.sh
./run-emulator.sh
```

For other cases I recommend: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice start. Not perfect yet, as it's a sandboxed environment, so no easy file access, I guess. But we'll get there one day, I'm sure :)

Comment: Good, this is available on Debian as well :)